# Multiple Dependent Rules FluentValidation

Tags: c#, .net-core, fluentvalidation

Just started using this awesome api, I am facing some issue with multiple `DependentRules`. I had rules like this

```
RuleFor(d => d.NotificationType).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
When(d => d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "EMAIL", () =>
{
    RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Invalid Email Address");
    RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");

});
When(d => d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "SMS", () =>
{
    RuleFor(d => d.NotificationContactNo).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
});
```

But this fails when `NotificationType` is `Empty`,it already raised the `Required` error. Now in this case these other rules are dependent rules and they should only execute when `NotificationType` is not empty. For this i have modified the rules as:

```
RuleFor(d => d.NotificationType).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required").DependentRules(k =>
    k.When(d => d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "EMAIL", () =>
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Invalid Email Address");
        RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
    })
);
RuleFor(d => d.NotificationType).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required").DependentRules(k =>
    When(d => d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "SMS", () =>
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.NotificationContactNo).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
    })
);
```

It is working but i am repeating this rule `d.NotificationType).NotEmpty()`, I want to achieve something like this, `Multiple Dependent Rules under one Rule`.

```
RuleFor(d => d.NotificationType).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required").DependentRules(k =>
    k.When(d => d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "EMAIL", () =>
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Invalid Email Address");
        RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
    });
    k.When(d => d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "SMS", () =>
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.NotificationContactNo).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
    })
);
```

Any idea how can i achieve this ?

Answer (score 9):

You should set the [CascadeMode](https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/d.-Configuring-a-Validator#setting-the-cascade-mode) on your first rule, so that the validation stops on the first failure.

```
RuleFor(d => d.NotificationType)
  .Cascade(CascadeMode.StopOnFirstFailure)
  .NotEmpty()
  .WithMessage("Required");
```

Comment: I don't wanna stop the validation on this point as there are other rules which need to be executed and show all the errors to the user.

Comment: This example no longer works with the current version

Answer (score 3):

It is not so elegant but you can avoid failure by modifying your conditions:

```
RuleFor(d => d.NotificationType).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");

When(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.NotificationType) && d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "EMAIL", () =>
{
    RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Invalid Email Address");
    RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");

});

When(d => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(d.NotificationType) && d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "SMS", () =>
{
    RuleFor(d => d.NotificationContactNo).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
});
```

Comment: This is what i have done, you are checking the `NotificationType` by `!string.IsNullOrEmpty` and i am doing it like `RuleFor(d => d.NotificationType).NotEmpty()`. It's all the same

Answer (score 2):

Your solution helped me by doing something like this

```
RuleFor(d => d.NotificationType).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required")
.DependentRules(k =>
    k.When(d => d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "EMAIL", () =>
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Invalid Email Address");
        RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
    })
).DependentRules(k =>
    k.When(d => d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "SMS", () =>
    {
        RuleFor(d => d.NotificationContactNo).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
    }));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use When(...).Otherwise(...) as nest When() statements

```
RuleFor(d => d.NotificationType).NotEmpty().WithMessage("NotificationType Required").DependentRules(() => {
                When(d => d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "EMAIL", () =>
                {
                    RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Email Required")
                    .EmailAddress().WithMessage("Invalid Email Address");
                    //RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).EmailAddress().WithMessage("Invalid Email Address");
                    //RuleFor(d => d.NotificationEmail).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Required");
                }).Otherwise(() => When(d => d.NotificationType.ToUpper() == "SMS", () =>
                {
                    RuleFor(d => d.NotificationContactNo).NotEmpty().WithMessage("ContactNo Required");

                }).Otherwise(() =>
                                {
                                    // Otherwise Validations
                                    //...
                                })
                   );
            });
```